# What version were generators and the yield keyword introduced in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

What version of Nodejs works with yield and generators?

```
const f = async function* generator() {
  yield 'foo';
}

const x = generator();
```

Comment: from version 4.0.0 https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator

Comment: how come it throws a syntax error on node 8? specifically, node v8.17.0

Comment: is it exatly this function you have provded us?

Comment: i think the issue was because i was trying to create an async generator